# malformed header from script index.py Bad header

Tags: python, apache

I want to run python code in apache2(ubuntu 14.04) server. I have followed these steps and getting Error:

Step 1:

Configuration 1: I have created a directory and file under

```
/var/www/cgi-bin
```

Configuration 2 : I have edited /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
Alias /cgi-bin /var/www/cgi-bin
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/cgi-bin>
Options All
</Directory>
```

Step 2:

and my python script is: index.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi;
import cgitb;cgitb.enable()

print "Content-Type: text/plain\n"

print "<b>Hello python</b>"
```

step 3:

When i ran through chrome browser using:
    URL : http://localhost/cgi-bin/index.py

step 4:

I am getting this Error in error-log

```
malformed header from script 'index.py': Bad header: Hello Python
```

Answer (score 20):

You should end your header with `\r\n`, then you must print out yet another `\r\n` to signal that the body is coming.

(In other words, it's interpreting your body as a Header because the headers were never terminated)

Answer (score 14):

**Try this script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi;
import cgitb;cgitb.enable()

print "Content-Type: text/html"
print "" #use this double quote print statement to add a blank line in the script
print "<b>Hello python</b>"
```

There should be one line space between header and main html content. That's why we have to use extra print statement before starting html tags in script.

Comment: For me this did output the HTML code directly to the browser. I got it to work by changing Context-Type: text/plain to Content-type: text/html

Comment: Sorry, I have just edited the code mentioned with the question.I missed that content-type mentioned there. I have done the same as you did it. Thanks for reminding me about that

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with the flush mechanism when you need to print a file.
This code responds to a http request if it is called via e.g. apache2.

```py
import sys

print("Content-type: image/png", end="\r\n\r\n", flush=True)
sys.stdout.buffer.write(bytes(open("file.png","rb").read()))
```

`end="\r\n\r\n"` adds an empty line to begin the body

`flush=True` forces python to print the lines as intended. In my case, the header was printed wrong.