# Flask - malformed header from script 'app.cgi': Bad header

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, apache, flask

I am making an `AJAX` call to my `python` script in `Flask`. The python script is returning a response object through `jsonify`.

The `python` script is deployed in `Apache24`.

```
return jsonify({"responseList": response}) # here response is a list
```

In my web browser I get the Error - 500 - Internal server error.
In the Apache logs, I see this error `malformed header from script 'app.cgi': Bad header`

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34825199/malformed-header-from-script-index-py-bad-header/34840700?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) that we need to give a new line between the header and the body to avoid this error. Is that really needed with `jsonify` or is there a way to give a new line, as `jsonify` adds the header on its own.

Please suggest.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to write your return line as follows:

```
import Response from flask
import json
...

return Response(json.dumps({"responseList": response}),  mimetype='application/json')
```