# How to change CORS header in Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, cors

I was trying to build an application to serve search queries to a website at a different domain. While experimenting with this on localhost, I ran into a CORS error: Cross Origin Request Blocked... (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). After a bit of research, I'm under the impression that this bug will follow me when I try to deploy.

The obvious solution is to add the header, for now with a value of *. I've looked around a little bit for possibilities of doing this in Flask, but I don't know how to implement anything.

https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled 
W3 simply suggests to print "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*". Needless to say, this doesn't work. They must be using python somewhere more basic...

[Flask - malformed header from script 'app.cgi': Bad header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49663355/flask-malformed-header-from-script-app-cgi-bad-header)
This question is seemingly related, because it does touch a CGI header (what even is that) and Flask, but I'm not really dealing with any responses in my script.

For reference, this is my flask script:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/search/<tag>")
def result(tag):
    return str(fullSearch(tag))

if __name__ = "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This script does work and correctly returns a stringified json when I manually visit "/search/anything".
This is my Ajax call:

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/search/anything");
request.onload = function(){
    console.log(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
}
request.send();
```

Again, it returns the CORS error.
How do I update the CORS header??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can try `flask_cors` package added on your project

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/search/<tag>")
def result(tag):
    return str(fullSearch(tag))

if __name__ = "__main__":
    app.run()
```